# How do I echo all of my taxonomies?

Tags: taxonomy

I'm trying to echo **all** of my custom taxonomies, but this only prints out the first one:

```
$skill_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'skill', array('fields' => 'names'));
echo 'skill-' . $term->slug;
```

Does anyone have an idea of what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function [wp_get_post_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/) returns *array* (or [WP_Error](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_error/) but we ommit it here) so you need go through the returned array and print all items:

```
$skill_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'skill', array('fields' => 'names'));
print_r( $skill_list );
```

Of course you can also yous `for` or `foreach` for better printing...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ondřej Doněk!

I ended up with this working solution:

```
$skill_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'skill', array('fields' => 'slugs'));

foreach( $skill_list as $slug ): 
    echo 'skill-' . $slug . ' ';
endforeach;
```

Comment: Glad to help...

Comment: Please accept an answer if your problem has been solved